# C++ OpenCV Read string instead of loadFromCSV

Tags: c++, csv, opencv

I am using OPENCV 3.0.0 and C++.

I need to read a csv type string instead of reading a csv file.

In the sample code , it uses

```
 Ptr<TrainData> data = TrainData::loadFromCSV(filename, 0, response_idx, response_idx+1, typespec);
```

How could I read a csv type string like this

```
string str1 = " 0,31,29,82,1,0,0,0,2,normal " ;
```

then can use it to TrainData ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Probably simplest thing would be to dump it into a temporary file and load that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)